# Spring Websockets Max Concurrent connections

Tags: websocket, tomcat7, spring-websocket

What is the max number of concurrent websocket connections a tomcat instance can support? We are looking to serve 20000 connections at any given time. What would be the recommended number of tomcat instances to support the load?

Comment: Guys.. I really need some insight on the performance of Spring Websockets on Tomcat. Will a 3 node tomcat cluster be enough to provision 20000-25000 concurrent connections?

Comment: Hi, Can you share what was your experience?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/cloudmark/spring-websockets-performance-testing
They use Tomcat 8 but i think there will not be a fundamental difference in performance.